# Index out of bound exception when did String Char Array convertion in Java

Tags: java, android

I am getting the exception when i try to run this part of the code.

```
        FifoN = FifoName.toCharArray();
        Log.i(ControlUnit.TV,"Char Value : "+ FifoN);
        tadClass.setFifoName(FifoN);
        Log.i(ControlUnit.TV,"TAD_SetFIFOname called with name "+ FifoN);
```

I am getting index out of bound exception error. What could be the reason. ?

Comment: post **logcat** and more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error *could* be because of an array element whose index is not defined by your code, that is your code is trying to access , say element 12, when the size is only 10. The error is *unlikely* to occur due to anything in **this code snippet**, rather it is due to something *before* it. Please post your logcat and more code so that someone can help you further.

Comment: It is something to do with the path i provided in the string which did not exist  , but when provided an existing path it worked.

Comment: If you are specifying file path as input to this code snippet, **always make sure it exists**, that is using , the if(file.exists){} check, before going on to this code. This could be a useful way to avoid such issues and make your code more robust.